# Procedural Map Generation

Tags: java, cocos2d-iphone, procedural-generation, love2d

I really want to start doing a tile game, and I've started Cocos2d because of the popularity of it and the availability of tutorials and resources.
But I really want to try out some procedural map generation, but unsure if Cocos2d is the one for it.

If it comes to it and Cocos2d isn't best for this then my other options are Java or Love2D, this isn't iOS but oh well!

Answer (score 2):

Because Cocos2D loads map files from an external source, what you want to do is write some code to generate a map file using the syntax described in [this manual page](https://github.com/bjorn/tiled/wiki/TMX-Map-Format), save the generated map file, then load it using Cocos2D's tiledMapWithTMXFile function (more information [here](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3atiled_maps#how_to_create_a_tmx_node))

for more information on writing a proccedural map generation algorithm, the [Procedural Content Generation Wiki](http://pcg.wikidot.com/pcg-algorithm%3amap-generation) is a great resource.

Answer (score 0):

A tutorial on procedurally generated caves, but it could work for top down maps and what not.

http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/cave-levels-cellular-automata--gamedev-9664